# The energy of an ultrashort pulse

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, laser

I read that some lasers can emit a light pulse in the range of [femtoseconds](http://www.pitt.edu/~jdnorton/Goodies/Chasing_the_light/light_wave.gif) 10^-15 s or even of [attoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attosecond) 10^-18 s.

Apparently, the latter can only be X-rays:

> In the specialized literature, "ultrashort" refers to the femtosecond
>   (fs) and picosecond (ps) range, although such pulses no longer hold
>   the record for the shortest pulses artificially generated. Indeed,
>   *x-ray pulses* with durations on the attosecond time scale have been
>   reported.

Is the duration 1/10^-15 (-18) s related to frequency (visible light: .8*10^15 , X-ray: 10^18 ) Hz  or to technical reasons?

But my question is this: what is the energy of a single pulse of light? the blunt definition relating Planck's constant  $h$ to 1 Hz, one pulse, would suggest that a pulse of a fs of blue light should have the same energy of 1 Hz of an X-ray lasting an attosecond, but something suggests that the latter should be more energetic than the former. So, what is the correct answer?

Comment: The peak power (energy per time) is much larger for the shorter pulses, that's why the X-ray does more damage even though energy over the whole duration of the pulse is the same.

Comment: $E=hf$ applies to one photon, which is not the same as one pulse.

Comment: @sammygerbil, so what? one mono-energetic pulse of N photons has E = Nhf

Comment: @Paul, the peak-power is larger but when you multiply it by a shorter time, do you get same energy if the number of photons is the same?

Comment: What is the $f$ of a pulse? It has many frequencies, not one. If it only had one $f$, it wouldn't be a pulse.

Comment: @sammygerbil, the answer says so, of course there can be negligible variations, but if the pulse is  red or blue light or whatever, *that* is the frequency.

Answer (score 1):

For mono-energetic radiation the total energy of a pulse is given by the number of photons in the pulse times the photon energy, so it really depends on the source and how many photons it can produce in total. We can build single photon sources and lasers that produce $MJ$ in total pulse energy, which is commensurate to $10^{25}$ quanta.

The limits to pulse timing only depend on the energy of the photons, however, so they are independent of the the actual pulse energy (pulses with many photons can be as short as pulses with a few). A photon energy of $1eV \approx 1.6\times 10^{-19}J$, the most often used unit to measure the energy of radiation, belongs to radiation in the near IR at around $1.2\mu m$ wavelength and the energy of visible photons is around $1.5-3eV$.

The energy-time uncertainty links these visible photons to a time uncertainty of approx. $2fs$, i.e. visible light can not be compressed to much shorter pulses. If we want to go thousand times shorter, the individual photon energy has to increase by a factor of 1000, which brings us into the soft x-ray energy range.

What is important to understand, though, is that a single photon is not a short pulse of light. It's just a unit of energy which, because of relativity, belongs to a commensurate unit of momentum. A photon also carries a helicity, which can be identified with a unit of angular momentum. The identification of a photon does *not* set a time scale for the length of an electromagnetic pulse. In order to speak about "a pulse" many photons have to be created or detected. Only in the limit of large photon number can we talk meaningfully about the spectral and temporal properties of an electromagnetic field.

Comment: Consider two ultrashort pulses of *light* containing same number of *photons*, say 10^30 , .8 fs for blue light and 1 as for x-ray, do they have same energy? is it 10^30 hHz =4*10^15 eV?

Comment: The pulse with the shorter wavelength has the larger energy... independent of the actual pulse length, of course. No instrument can detect a single photon of any frequency. For the detection of the lowest energy photons one would probably use a bolometer, but ultimately all methods will run into a thermodynamic temperature limit because of noise, both in the detector and the surrounding electromagnetic field.

Comment: Is it *at all* possible to compare the energy of two pulses? How do we know that the values recorded by the bolometer refer to pulses with an equal number of photons? If the comparison is just theoretical, considering my previous comment,  what is roughly the difference in energy between the two pulses with a wavelength 1000 greater? *Paul* said that power is larger, and that is obvious since same energy in shorter time gives larger power, but what is the ratio of energy, which is basically my question

Comment: Yes, of course we can compare different type of radiation, but we won't be using just the total energy, in addition we would also measure the spectrum, which tells us the distribution of energy. I am not sure why you are so interested in these things, though, ultrashort pulses don't exist in nature and when we make them, we know pretty well what's in there.

Comment: If you know pretty well what is in there, answer my first comment or expand your answer and give some details on: how you make a mono-energetic pulse of E = hf, how do you count the number N of photons in a pulse, and what is the energy of two pulses with equal number N of photons with ratio of f /t/ $lambda$ 1/1000, and I'll accept your answer.